# Selling content in the app and on website

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

We have an app selling content (ebooks) within the app and InApp
Purchase. The app works with API and website. Books also can be bought
through the website. Right now we have no synchronisation of
purchases/books between the app and website.

In next update we want to make a userform with login and password for
the website and synchronisation of purchased content between the
website and the app. So, all purchases made through the website will
be available in the app and vice versa, if books are bought within the
app, they are available on the website. To accomplish this we will
change the prices both on the site and in the app to make them the
same.

The question is - isn't this scheme in contradiction with Apple Rules
and will they allow an update of this kind in AppStore? Won't the app
be blocked in a short time?

Thanks in advance for the answers and ideas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We too sell eBooks on the app store, our app sells in-app items and we also have a website
We have researched alot in apple docs and we found no contradiction in doing so.
So our reasoning is like this

We will have 2 types of users:

- Users with no website account
- Users with a website account

For the users with no website account they will continue their purchases of books normally as they did before, they will normally buy books using in-app, only the books that are added to the website as in-app will be available here (we reached in-app limitation of 10K in-app items, so right now we have more than 20K items that are not registered as in-app. these items will not be shown in our store page whitin the app)

For the users with a website account, they can either buy books using in-app, or they can buy books from the web browser (outside our application) they will use their normal visa card and continue their purchases

When a user who has an account logs in our application, all his paid books (the one bought from our website) will be available for free in his app. this will not be against apple rules since these items will be free.

When the user buys a book using in-app, if he is registered we synch this book to his website account, and he will be able to read this book from our website.
As soon as the user logs in, we send all the items he has in his library to the website for synching.
If the user logout we hide all the items that he bought from the website using his account.

Comment: Hi Omar,can you please mention the link of the application and the website as well.We are facing the same kind of problem  so i think this may help us a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Well what i understand from your question is that.

You need to synchronize your user data across all domains (e.g iOS,Web etc.).

Here's what you need to do.

- Change the structure of your iOS app that fits to your needs.In your case working with synchronized data that comes from the same source and user login.
- Update your current application and submit it to Apple for review.
- Wait for it to be reviewed and republished as a new version of your current app.

And as far as i know there's no contradiction for what you want to achieve.Since you are selling your own products with your own system it's just normal that you want to do something like this.